# How to find related SqlCommand object

Tags: .net, windbg, sos, sosex

I am looking into a dump file for high memory issue. One thing that stands out in that dump file is over 300,000 DataRow objects. We run queries against sql database that are stored in-memory DataTable objects. 
I would like to know that what query is responsible for creating so many DataRow objects. I can see various fields in DataRow and DataTable object but cannot figure out how to find related SqlCommand object because that should 
give me access to CommandText and thus the query. Can someone help me out figuring out how to get to SqlCommand object?

```
0:000> !do 00000001003c0b98 
Name:        System.Data.DataRow
MethodTable: 000007fef5f4b880
EEClass:     000007fef5dc4348
Size:        96(0x60) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fef5f4a548  4000752        8 ...em.Data.DataTable  0 instance 00000001601a6610 _table
000007fef5f4c100  4000753       10 ...aColumnCollection  0 instance 00000001601a6900 _columns
000007fef8a1c9d0  4000754       38         System.Int32  1 instance           326255 oldRecord
000007fef8a1c9d0  4000755       3c         System.Int32  1 instance           326255 newRecord
000007fef8a1c9d0  4000756       40         System.Int32  1 instance               -1 tempRecord
000007fef8a37fa8  4000757       30         System.Int64  1 instance 326256 _rowID
000007fef64408b8  4000758       44         System.Int32  1 instance                0 _action
000007fef8a1d800  4000759       54       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 inChangingEvent
000007fef8a1d800  400075a       55       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 inDeletingEvent
000007fef8a1d800  400075b       56       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 inCascade
000007fef5f4b768  400075c       18 ...m.Data.DataColumn  0 instance 0000000000000000 _lastChangedColumn
000007fef8a1c9d0  400075d       48         System.Int32  1 instance                0 _countColumnChange
000007fef6462910  400075e       20 ...em.Data.DataError  0 instance 0000000000000000 error
000007fef8a15c40  400075f       28        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 _element
000007fef8a1c9d0  4000760       4c         System.Int32  1 instance         11865584 _rbTreeNodeId
000007fef8a1c9d0  4000762       50         System.Int32  1 instance           753591 ObjectID
000007fef8a1c9d0  4000761      548         System.Int32  1   shared           static _objectTypeCount
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000014d8430:NotInit  0000000002e08b30:NotInit  <<


0:000> !do 00000001601a6610 
Name:        System.Data.DataTable
MethodTable: 000007fef5f4a548
EEClass:     000007fef5dc4110
Size:        512(0x200) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fef7d0fa50  40003b7        8 ...ponentModel.ISite  0 instance 0000000000000000 site
000007fef7d0e708  40003b8       10 ....EventHandlerList  0 instance 0000000000000000 events
000007fef8a15c40  40003b6      3d0        System.Object  0   shared           static EventDisposed
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000014d8430:NotInit  0000000002e08b30:NotInit  <<
000007fef5f49740  40007d7       18  System.Data.DataSet  0 instance 00000001601a5f20 dataSet
000007fef5f4bbb8  40007d8       20 System.Data.DataView  0 instance 0000000000000000 defaultView
000007fef8a37fa8  40007d9      1a0         System.Int64  1 instance 2849445 nextRowID
000007fef5f4c210  40007da       28 ...DataRowCollection  0 instance 00000001601a6aa0 rowCollection
000007fef5f4c100  40007db       30 ...aColumnCollection  0 instance 00000001601a6900 columnCollection
000007fef5f4c188  40007dc       38 ...straintCollection  0 instance 00000001601a6a40 constraintCollection
000007fef8a1c9d0  40007dd      1a8         System.Int32  1 instance                2 elementColumnCount
000007fef5f4aeb8  40007de       40 ...elationCollection  0 instance 0000000000000000 parentRelationsCollection
000007fef5f4aeb8  40007df       48 ...elationCollection  0 instance 0000000000000000 childRelationsCollection
000007fef5f4c0a0  40007e0       50 ...ata.RecordManager  0 instance 00000001601a68a0 recordManager
0000000000000000  40007e1       58                       0 instance 00000001601a7070 indexes
0000000000000000  40007e2       60                       0 instance 0000000000000000 shadowIndexes
000007fef8a1c9d0  40007e3      1ac         System.Int32  1 instance                0 shadowCount
000007fef6465340  40007e4       68 ...ropertyCollection  0 instance 0000000000000000 extendedProperties
000007fef8a16ae8  40007e5       70        System.String  0 instance 000000017fb08258 tableName
000007fef8a16ae8  40007e6       78        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 tableNamespace
000007fef8a16ae8  40007e7       80        System.String  0 instance 00000000ffb00488 tablePrefix
000007fef5f4ee58  40007e8       88 ...ta.DataExpression  0 instance 0000000000000000 displayExpression
000007fef8a1d800  40007e9      1c4       System.Boolean  1 instance                1 fNestedInDataset
000007fef8a23fd0  40007ea       90 ...ation.CultureInfo  0 instance 0000000120122eb8 _culture
000007fef8a1d800  40007eb      1c5       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 _cultureUserSet
000007fef8a1d588  40007ec       98 ...ation.CompareInfo  0 instance 0000000000000000 _compareInfo
0000000000000000  40007ed      1b0         System.Int32  1 instance               25 _compareFlags
0000000000000000  40007ee       a0                       0 instance 0000000120122eb8 _formatProvider
0000000000000000  40007ef       a8                       0 instance 00000001601a70e8 _hashCodeProvider
000007fef8a1d800  40007f0      1c6       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 _caseSensitive
000007fef8a1d800  40007f1      1c7       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 _caseSensitiveUserSet
000007fef8a16ae8  40007f2       b0        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 encodedTableName
000007fef5f4b768  40007f3       b8 ...m.Data.DataColumn  0 instance 0000000000000000 xmlText
000007fef5f4b768  40007f4       c0 ...m.Data.DataColumn  0 instance 0000000000000000 _colUnique
000007fef8a1d800  40007f5      1c8       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 textOnly
000007fef8a383d0  40007f6      1d8       System.Decimal  1 instance 00000001601a67e8 minOccurs
000007fef8a383d0  40007f7      1e8       System.Decimal  1 instance 00000001601a67f8 maxOccurs
000007fef8a1d800  40007f8      1c9       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 repeatableElement
000007fef8a15c40  40007f9       c8        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 typeName
000007fef6463058  40007fd       d0 ....UniqueConstraint  0 instance 0000000000000000 primaryKey
000007fef5f4b8e0  40007ff       d8 ...Data.IndexField[]  0 instance 000000017fb683b8 _primaryIndex
000007fef8a1aff0  4000800       e0      System.Object[]  0 instance 0000000000000000 delayedSetPrimaryKey
000007fef5f4cbf0  4000801       e8    System.Data.Index  0 instance 0000000000000000 loadIndex
000007fef5f4cbf0  4000802       f0    System.Data.Index  0 instance 0000000000000000 loadIndexwithOriginalAdded
000007fef5f4cbf0  4000803       f8    System.Data.Index  0 instance 0000000000000000 loadIndexwithCurrentDeleted
000007fef8a1c9d0  4000804      1b4         System.Int32  1 instance                0 _suspendIndexEvents
000007fef8a1d800  4000805      1ca       System.Boolean  1 instance                1 savedEnforceConstraints
000007fef8a1d800  4000806      1cb       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 inDataLoad
000007fef8a1d800  4000807      1cc       System.Boolean  1 instance                1 initialLoad
000007fef8a1d800  4000808      1cd       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 schemaLoading
000007fef8a1d800  4000809      1ce       System.Boolean  1 instance                1 enforceConstraints
000007fef8a1d800  400080a      1cf       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 _suspendEnforceConstraints
000007fef8a1d800  400080b      1d0       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 fInitInProgress
000007fef8a1d800  400080c      1d1       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 inLoad
000007fef8a1d800  400080d      1d2       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 fInLoadDiffgram
000007fef8a1c350  400080e      1d3          System.Byte  1 instance                2 _isTypedDataTable
000007fef8a1aff0  400080f      100      System.Object[]  0 instance 0000000000000000 EmptyDataRowArray
000007fef7d0db28  4000810      108 ...criptorCollection  0 instance 0000000000000000 propertyDescriptorCollectionCache
000007fef8a1aff0  4000812      110      System.Object[]  0 instance 000000017fb683d0 _nestedParentRelations
0000000000000000  4000813      118                       0 instance 0000000000000000 dependentColumns
000007fef8a1d800  4000814      1d4       System.Boolean  1 instance                0 mergingData
000007fef6464140  4000815      120 ...hangeEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onRowChangedDelegate
000007fef6464140  4000816      128 ...hangeEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onRowChangingDelegate
000007fef6464140  4000817      130 ...hangeEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onRowDeletingDelegate
000007fef6464140  4000818      138 ...hangeEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onRowDeletedDelegate
000007fef6462898  4000819      140 ...hangeEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onColumnChangedDelegate
000007fef6462898  400081a      148 ...hangeEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onColumnChangingDelegate
000007fef6464678  400081b      150 ...ClearEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onTableClearingDelegate
000007fef6464678  400081c      158 ...ClearEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onTableClearedDelegate
000007fef6464700  400081d      160 ...ewRowEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onTableNewRowDelegate
000007fef7cf0790  400081e      168 ...angedEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onPropertyChangingDelegate
000007fef8a2e1d8  400081f      170  System.EventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 onInitialized
000007fef5f4cc78  4000820      178 ...ta.DataRowBuilder  0 instance 00000001601a7098 rowBuilder
0000000000000000  4000821      180                       0 instance 00000001601a6810 delayedViews
0000000000000000  4000822      188                       0 instance 00000001601a6838 _dataViewListeners
000007fef8a21db0  4000823      190 ...ections.Hashtable  0 instance 0000000000000000 rowDiffId
000007fef8a233f0  4000824      198 ....ReaderWriterLock  0 instance 00000001601a6860 indexesLock
000007fef8a1c9d0  4000825      1b8         System.Int32  1 instance               -1 ukColumnPositionForInference
000007fef6440a70  4000826      1bc         System.Int32  1 instance                0 _remotingFormat
000007fef8a1c9d0  4000828      1c0         System.Int32  1 instance             3838 _objectID
000007fef8a1c960  40007fa      290       System.Int32[]  0   shared           static zeroIntegers
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000014d8430:NotInit  0000000002e08b30:000000017fb68360 <<
000007fef8a1aff0  40007fb      298      System.Object[]  0   shared           static zeroColumns
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000014d8430:NotInit  0000000002e08b30:000000017fb68378 <<
000007fef8a1aff0  40007fc      2a0      System.Object[]  0   shared           static zeroRows
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000014d8430:NotInit  0000000002e08b30:000000017fb68398 <<
000007fef5f4b8e0  40007fe      2a8 ...Data.IndexField[]  0   shared           static zeroIndexField
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000014d8430:NotInit  0000000002e08b30:000000017fb683b8 <<
000007fef8a1aff0  4000811      2b0      System.Object[]  0   shared           static EmptyArrayDataRelation
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000014d8430:NotInit  0000000002e08b30:000000017fb683d0 <<
000007fef8a1c9d0  4000827      558         System.Int32  1   shared           static _objectTypeCount
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000014d8430:NotInit  0000000002e08b30:3851 <<
```

Comment: You could try using ClrDbg on sourceforge.

Comment: You can try `!gcroot` on the address of the object to see the "parents" of the object and check the properties of those to see if you find a relationship to SqlCommand.

Comment: There is also netext, which has a nice [`!wfrom`](https://netext.codeplex.com/#wfrom) command to select objects from memory. Compared to a `!dumpheap -type` this allows a narrowed output of objects

Comment: @Loathing: What does ClrDbg give me to know the relationship?

Comment: @Thomas: I was trying to use !gcroot to find some relationship but so far haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: A faster option is to run !sosex.bhi to build an index.  Then !sosex.mroot on the object to find its path to root.  Once the index is built, !mroot returns nearly instantaneously.

Comment: @johnsmith It provides a user-interface to point and click around objects in the heap, their references, and which objects reference them. It might be an easier tool to use.

Comment: @johnsmith As for your particular problem, you should watch out for using the `dataTable.NewRow()` method because it caches the row in some underlying `RowCollection` even if it is never added to the `DataTable`. (I ran into that problem thinking the `DataRow`s would be garbage collected if it wasn't added to the table). Although, it could also be a SQL query as you suspect. You could also turn on logging on the SQL server and match the timestamp of the crash with the SQL query log.